# LLenar arreglo sin numeros repetidos

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Necesito llenar un arreglo mediante un textbox. Lo que quiero es que al querer agregar un número de Id Repetido me aparezca un mensaje diciendo que el numero ya está dentro del arreglo y no lo agregue nuevamente. Utilizo C# con xamarin forms

```
int[] arreglo = new int[200];

for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.Length;)
{
  arreglo[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Id.Text);

}
```

Comment: Francamente tu código no tiene ningún sentido

Comment: Puse solo esa parte porque tengo mas funciones dentro de un boton al llenar el Id.Text preciono el boton y me agrega al arreglo pero quisiera que no se repitiera el id en el arreglo

Comment: Pero como no se te van a repetir si estas agregando siempre el mismo valor, es que no tiene sentido alguno

Comment: Ohh Con razon no trabajaba como lo esperaba, entonces cual seria la estructura para llenar el arreglo y que cumpla con lo demas que no agrege repetidos y muestre el mensaje espero puedas ayudarme Saludos

Comment: Y tiene que ser un arreglo?? no pude ser una lista?

Comment: Tambien me serviria al final la funcion que me ayudaria mucho es que el valor solo se agrege una ves que no se repita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Usando Contains y arreglo**

```
int[] arreglo = new int[200]; //esto debería ser variable global
int indice=0; //esto debería ser variable global
int valor = Convert.ToInt32(Id.Text);

if (!arreglo.Contains(valor))
{
  arreglo[indice] = valor;
  indice++;
}
```

**2) Usando Linq y arreglo**

```
int[] arreglo = new int[200]; //esto debería ser variable global
int indice=0; //esto debería ser variable global
int valor = Convert.ToInt32(Id.Text);

if (!arreglo.Any(a=>a==valor))
{
  arreglo[indice] = valor;
  indice++;
}
```

**3) usando lista y contains**

```
List<int> arreglo =new List<int>(); //esto debería ser variable global
int valor = Convert.ToInt32(Id.Text);

if (!arreglo.Contains(valor))
{
  arreglo.Add(valor);
}
```

**4) usando Linq y listas**

```
List<int> arreglo =new List<int>(); //esto debería ser variable global
int valor = Convert.ToInt32(Id.Text);

if (!arreglo.Any(a=>a==valor))
{
  arreglo.Add(valor);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Yussef en verdad

Comment: Donde aparece esa parte para aceptarlas de una vez No sabia disculpa

Comment: Deja lo busco Oye por otra parte Aplique todos  tus metodos solo que agrege un else en los if para que me mostrara un mensaje si el valor a introducir es repetido y ninguno callo dentro del else todos los numero que añadi los agrego aunque fueran repetidos.

Comment: Dejaste la lista o el arreglo como variable global??

Comment: Si solo agrege el else con el mensaje en los 4 ejemplos mira  List<int> arreglo = new List<int>(); //esto debería ser variable global
                        int valor = Convert.ToInt32(Id.Text);

                        if (!arreglo.Contains(valor))
                        {
                            arreglo.Add(valor);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await DisplayAlert("Advertencia", "Repetido", "Cerrar");

                        }

Comment: Si dame un momento

Comment: Listo yoseff asi les agrege el else a los 4 ejemplos